# Contraction Mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$$f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}1/4 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1/3 & 0\\ -1/2 & 0 & 1/4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad\forall x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb R^3 $$

I am able to prove that this function is a contraction w/ standard Euclidean metric via using polar coordinates. I have heard that it is also possible to show this via finding the operator norm. How would one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\|f(x)\| = \|Ax\| \leq \|A\| \|x\|,$$
by the definition of the operator norm:
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.
$$
In case of Euclidean norm and $A: \mathbb{R}^3\to  \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation:
$$
 \|A\|  = \sqrt{\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(A^T A)},
$$
where $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(A^T A)$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, and you wanna check this is less than $1$.

In your case: 
$$
A^T A = \begin{pmatrix}5/16 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/9 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 5/16 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which gives the $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}} = 5/16$, and $\|A\| = \sqrt{5}/4 < 1$, thus 
$$
\|f(x)\| = \|Ax\| \leq \|A\| \|x\| < \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\|x\|
$$
and $f$ is a contraction.

Comment: Could you possibly elucidate with a numerical example?